# Discrete math(Divisors and primes)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is the following statement true or false?Explain.
There are integers $x,y,$ and $z$ such that $14$ divides $2^x  × 3^y ×  5^z$.

My guess is false but I don't know how to explain it?Does it have anything to do with the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an intuitive explanation

Yes $14$ does not divide $2^x  × 3^y ×  5^z$ for any integers $x,y,z$ because

$14=2 × 7$

Since there are no seven's  in the expression..It will never fully divide it